# Can I easily modify classes in Dart libraries?

Tags: attributes, dart

I am using the pathfinding library, but I am wondering in general not just for this single situation. 
It provides a class Grid which uses a class Node to hold basic informations. The documentations of Node says:

```
[...] and custom attributes may be added, depending on the algorithms' needs.
```

Is there a way to define attributes for Node (like steppedOnXTimes)? More specifically I want the to add the attributes to the original Node class or overwrite it, just extending it would not suffice since the Grid would still use the original Node class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this. The [pathfinding library](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/pathfinding) was ported from a [JavaScript version](https://github.com/qiao/PathFinding.js) and I guess the documentation was not updated to reflect this.

For your situation, the best you can do is probably to extend [grid.dart](https://github.com/pavelgj/PathFinding.dart/blob/master/lib/core/grid.dart) and provide a custom constructor and implementation of `_buildNodes` that uses your own Node class that extends the provided Node class.

There is no general solution that I am aware of.